# Difference between using apps from Applications or from some normal folder

Tags: terminal, mac, applications, zsh

When I download an application like Eclipse, Postman etc, Mac ask me to drag the app into Applications folder. Another way which I follow is to save this .app file in some folder and use it from there.
For example, I have made a folder `Software/` and the keep the apps here. Now if I have to run these file I go to the location where executable file reside `Software/Folder1/Folder2/...` and then run this file.
Out of these 2 ways which method is better for the Mac (I have no problem using executable file method). Mac also prompts that if I will use Applications folder my apps will be updated. I am a new mac user and have no idea what people generally use or which method is better. Please help by listing pros and cons! (Every answer is appreciated)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There’s no functional difference. The system runs apps from where ever you want to store it. Unless the [developer has done some very specific and non-standard things](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/153672/5472), Apple says apps should run anywhere they sit as a rule.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202635

If you need an app in LaunchPad and if it’s not showing,  you can also store in in your home folder - make a new Applications folder there and drag it over, but most people can store them where it makes you most happy or efficient and ignore the Applications location. The only reason for that is if you want another user on the Mac to share the same version of the app.

Comment: So it is fine if I dont store my apps in Applications?

Comment: Yes, in fact people often store apps in an app folder in their home folder. The only thing you might miss is launchpad access